# Request for advice about studying for a degree in partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm studying math by myself. I think my interest is more of applied math or math for engineers. I have finished studying "Engineering Mathematics" and "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" by K. A. Stroud. I'm now wondering if what I have learned from Stroud's books will be enough for me to pursue a masters degree in partial differential equations. If not, what other book(s) would you recommend for me to read and what course can I pursue with what I have learned? Merci beacoup!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some differential calculus, differential geometry, and a some applied mathematics. That should get you on the right track.